# Search page is not showing correct number of items

Tags: search, search-results

I have a search page in MOSS 2007.
When I search for an item like 'cd' then it shows 1-30 of about 95000 items, but I have only 27000 items for cd.

On the next page it shows the correct number of items, i.e. 31-60 of about 27000.

Please help me resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen, this is expected behavior in the way search results are returned.  The first page is an approximation and as you page through, the results become more accurate as it's working to fetch all the applicable results.

Comment: is there is any setting by which we can solve this?

Comment: Not that I have seen, I haven't fully dug into Search customizations, but I have seen it mentioned on other blogs as just the way it works.

Comment: hi Pirate, can u give me the blog link ?

Comment: I don't have them bookmarked.  I just remember reading it on a few blogs.  It returns what it thinks are the most relevant results, and as you page through, continues to refine the number of results more accurately.